# Event-based programming in Racket? (for UDP file transfer system)

Tags: sockets, events, racket

I've been tasked with doing some socket programming to implement a UDP file transfer program with two kinds of reliable data transfers. Because I have been given the liberty of language, I have chosen Racket, though mostly because I have always liked Lisps.

I've been looking through the Racket API for events and threads, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. I'm seeing all the `sync` functions, but those block. One thing I'd like to have is the ability to do some work while waiting for those events (even maybe print out randoms).

Does anyone have some resources I can refer to about this style of event-based programming in Racket? APIs are great and all, but are a little vague and a bit of "hands-on" learning.

Comment: Have you looked at the [section in The Racket Guide on concurrency](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/concurrency.html)? It has some examples on using threads, sync, and other concurrency tools. Basically, the easiest way to get concurrency in Racket is to spawn threads and just do the work there. Threads are lightweight, so you can spawn as many as you need, and you can use async channels to communicate between them. You use `sync` when you want to block the current thread until something has completed, so you can also use it to wait for worker threads to finish.

Comment: This question is probably too vague/broad for StackOverflow (see [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). Can you narrow it down to a specific programming task or piece of code involving events that you are trying to understand?